# What is type in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atlaskit

Well, I saw this code snippet that's down below and I'd like to know what `type Props` really is? Is it related to flow? Or is it related to prop-types?

**How do I use it in a component that's defined as a class?**

I saw it in the React-Router example found here: https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/core/navigation

The code snippet:

```
// @flow
import React from "react";
import { AtlassianIcon } from "@atlaskit/logo";
import Lorem from "react-lorem-component";
import Page from "@atlaskit/page";
import Navigation, { AkContainerTitle } from "@atlaskit/navigation";
import RouterLinkComponent from "./RouterLinkComponent";
import RouterLinkItem from "./RouterLinkItem";

// @flow

type Props = {
  title: string,
  currentPath: string
};

const PageNavigation = ({ title, currentPath }: Props) => (
  <Page
    navigation={
      <Navigation
        containerHeaderComponent={() => (
          <AkContainerTitle
            href="/iframe.html"
            icon={<AtlassianIcon label="atlassian" />}
            linkComponent={RouterLinkComponent}
            text="Dashboard"
          />
        )}
        globalPrimaryIcon={<AtlassianIcon label="Home" size="small" />}
        globalPrimaryItemHref="/iframe.html"
        linkComponent={RouterLinkComponent}
      >
        <RouterLinkItem
          text="Page 1"
          to="/page1"
          isSelected={currentPath === "/page1"}
        />
        <RouterLinkItem
          text="Page 2"
          to="/page2"
          isSelected={currentPath === "/page2"}
        />
        <RouterLinkItem
          text="Page 3"
          to="/page3"
          isSelected={currentPath === "/page3"}
        />
        <RouterLinkItem
          text="Page 4"
          to="/page4"
          isSelected={currentPath === "/page4"}
        />
      </Navigation>
    }
  >
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <Lorem count="30" />
    </div>
  </Page>
);

export default PageNavigation;
```

Comment: It’s related to prop types. You define a data type to the each property you receive or you send whatever in react

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's part of the flow type checker. See the docs: [Type Aliases](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/aliases/)

If it was PropTypes then it would look like this:

```
PageNavigation.propTypes = {
  title: string,
  currentPath: string
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful list of prop-types

```
ComponentName.propTypes = {
  someVariablePropNameA: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  someVariablePropNameB: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  someVariablePropNameC: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  someVariablePropNameD: PropTypes.number,
  someVariablePropNameE: PropTypes.bool
};
```

These are the expected props data types which are expected to be inside the component, usually passed into the component. Failed prop-types shouldn't break component but will show error, warning you they failed... We usually view this in our console log...

In addition, you can have default prop types like so

```
MatchRating.defaultProps = {
  someVariablePropNameA: "",
  someVariablePropNameB: {},
  someVariablePropNameC: [{}],
  someVariablePropNameD: 0,
  someVariablePropNameE: false
};
```

You need to include this package in your header like so

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
```

This is just a little means of testing for bugs. Should always be used.

Now for a full example

---

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ComponentName extends PureComponent {
}

ComponentName.propTypes = {

};

ComponentName.defaultProps = {

};

export default ComponentName;
```

---

Hope this helps